# Getting an array of un-named json tuple from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core

In appsettings.json I have unnamed json:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {"fruit": "apple"},
        {"fruit": "cherry"},
        {"fruit": "tomato"},
        {"vegetable": "carrot"},
        {"vegetable": "tomato"}
    ]
}
```

Now I want it in a list or array of tuples variable. I'm looking for simplest code (maybe .net core 2050 lol) like:

```
public static readonly IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
...
var items = config.GetValue<(string,string)[]>("Items");
var items = config.GetValue<List<(string,string)>>("Items");
```

What would be a simple solution since the line above doesn't work. I'm looking for something that would replace this part: "config.GetValue<(string,string)[]>("Items");"

Tried those:

```
(string,string)[] items = config.GetSection("Items")
  .GetChildren()
  .ToList()
  .Select(x => (x.Key,x.Value)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"{items.Length}, {items[1]}"); // 2, (1, )
```

```
var items = config.GetValue<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>("Items"); // null

var items = config.GetValue<List<Tuple<string,string>>>("Items"); // null

var items = config.GetValue<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>("Items"); // null

var items = config.GetSection("Items")
  .GetChildren()
  .Select(x => new Tuple<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value));
foreach (var item in items) Console.WriteLine($"({item.Item1},{item.Item2})"); // (0,) (1,)
```

Comment: Have you tried dictionary instead of tuples `config.GetValue<Dictionary<string,string>>("Items");`

Comment: I tried Dictionary<string,string>, but no luck.

Comment: A dictionary has the problem that it only allows a key once. The example holds multiple fruits and vegetables.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Configuration.GetSection(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration.getsection?view=net-5.0) to obtain the value corresponding to the `Items` key first & then construct an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>>` from the children values.

```
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("Items");

var data = section
.GetChildren()
.Select(x => new Tuple<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value));
```

Comment: I already tried those solutions. They don't work at all. Also, I have to use this un-named (tags are variable) json.

Comment: @AlainTrépanier it's helpful to include what you have already tried in your question to help answerers avoid suggesting solutions that didn't work for you. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more helpful guidelines.

Comment: All your suggestions return null

Comment: public static readonly IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

Comment: this does not work

Comment: @AlainTrépanier Thanks for the info, I've now updated the answer - this should work 

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you can use the "Bind" method like this:

```
    private List<T> GetList<T>(string configSection)
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        config.GetSection($"{configSection}").Bind(result);
        return result;
    }
```

You can call this method like this

```
GetList<Dictionary<string, string>>("Items");
```

**You need to reference nuget Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder**

Notice I wrapped the logic into a method... But you can just use the code directly without wrapping a method like this:

```
        var items= new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
        config.GetSection("Items").Bind(result);
```

Now what you get is a List of Dictionaries.  But it is because of the "shape" of your JSON.

It can be simplified to a single dictionary like this:

```
{
    "Items":  {
           "Item1": "Content1",
           "Item2": "Content2"
        }    
}
```

and then calling this code:

```
        var items= new Dictionary<string, string>();
        config.GetSection("Items").Bind(result);
```

In my opinion the last option in which you get single dictionary is better and more scalable.

Comment: @AlainTrépanier if this answer helped you can you please mark as the correct answer.  Thank you.

Comment: No you don't "need" an array of tuples. You could supply the configuration as a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

Comment: It cannot be simplified to a single dictionary since I don't have distinct keys.

Comment: A dictionary has the problem that it only allows a key once. The example holds multiple fruits and vegetables.

Comment: @monty the original question had unique keys... the OP edited the question days after it was answered to include duplicate keys.... which effectively changes the question completely

Comment: @monty also the code works just fine with the example... did you try it? the example is a list of dictionaries not a single dictionary... so it works just fine

Comment: in VS 2019 VS already complains within the appsettings json once you have 2 entries with Item1. But works with curly braces around the entries like: {"Item1": "Content1"} So not saying your solution does not work. Actually it's the one I picked :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> items = Configuration
            .GetSection("Items")
            .Get<Dictionary<string, string>[]>()
            .SelectMany(i => i)
            .ToList();
```

how to use examples

```
foreach (var item in items) 
    Console.WriteLine($"({item.Key},{item.Value})");

             var item1=items[0];
             var item2=items[1];
            var item1Key = item1.Key;
            var item1Value = item1.Value;
```

or you can continue to convert it to dictionary

```
            var dict=items.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            var item1 = dict["Item1"]; // = "Content1"
            var item2 = dict["Item2"]; // = "Content2"
```

Comment: I cannot since my code won't know the keys here "Item1" and "Item2".

Comment: @AlainTrépanier But  what your code knows?

Comment: Each instance of my code will use different Items to fill a gui that has a list of items per categories.

Comment: @Serge I need a help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431199/encoding-arraybuffer-to-base64-and-passing-it-to-mvc-controller-doesnt-work-for

Comment: I have the code here for demo https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkGMSNxvuE7Wgj9_c6cG8iHTgjjG?e=Wuwy3w

Comment: @Developer I am sorry, I would like to help you, but I cant offer anything without test , 
  I don't have installed the old net version to test.

Comment: Oh ok, can you tell how can we pass the max json string from api to controller. I tried several things like creating custom filter and all but none of them work

Comment: i am nearly getting 14MB data and can be more depending on the form and data

Comment: You can copy my code to .net core and see

Comment: A dictionary has the problem that it only allows a key once. The example holds multiple fruits and vegetables.